# Angular 5 bind to a custom properties

Tags: angular

i have angular component pass value to child component and that child use this value within ngFor , the parent component get the original value from service do http request .

this is the parent component passing "cats" which came form http request promise to child prop [catsToShow]

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ddlContainer clearfix">
    <select class='select-option' [(ngModel)]='selectedCat' (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
      <option *ngFor='let cat of cats' [value]="cat.name">{{cat.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <app-add-modal [catsToShow]="cats"></app-add-modal>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.body}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is the child component try to generate ngFor :

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success addNewModalOpener" (click)="openAddNewModal()">Add New</button>
</div>
<div id="addNewModal" class="formAddContainer">
  <form class="formAdd">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="body" />
    <select class='select-option form-control'>
      <option *ngFor='let cat of catsToShow' [value]="cat.name">{{cat.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">add</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

    declare var $:any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-modal',
      templateUrl: './add-modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-modal.component.scss']
    })
    export class AddModalComponent implements OnInit{

      @Input() catsToShow;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {

          $(".formAddContainer").iziModal({ width: '80%', padding: 10, borderBottom: false, background: 'rgba(136, 160, 185,0)' });
          $('#addNewModal').iziModal('open');
        
      }

    }
```

i am using iziModal to init a box for user to start collecting data , the dropdownlist appear to user without the ngFor generated items ... so how to sync the binded input value [catsToShow] first to generate ngFor list then show those items to user in iziModal box

Comment: Do you see any error message in your browser's console?

Comment: no errors the ngFor list is just empty

Comment: But cats works in the parentComponent. I mean there it definitely contains values which are shown?

Comment: yes cats have values if i wrap code within setTimeout for 1 sec the list will be generated

Comment: @andrewsaeed, you're mixing jquery stuff with angular, of course it doesn't work because they know nothing about each other and do not watch for any changes that might have happened in the neighbour's area. That said, and as others are trying to give you a hint, most likely the problem is with how you initialize that collection in the first place, but that code is not included here. Please do it.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov ok i know that jquery and angular are different logic that is why i am sync sending data to child component after that this component will start to use that data , so how to wait until the value reach the child after that another module will be able to use that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait with the instantiation of your modal until the list definitely has arrived.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

    declare var $:any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-modal',
      templateUrl: './add-modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-modal.component.scss']
    })
    export class AddModalComponent implements OnInit{

      @Input() catsToShow;

      constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() {}

     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

        if(changes.catsToShow) {

           $(".formAddContainer").iziModal({ width: '80%', padding: 10, borderBottom: false, background: 'rgba(136, 160, 185,0)' });
           $('#addNewModal').iziModal('open');

        }

    }
```

Comment: after days of searching i found that when you deal with html Dom elements focus on one approach so do it with jquery approach or angular approach from start to finish , thank you for help